# Laravel pushing jobs into different queue with low priority

Tags: php, laravel, queue, beanstalkd

Right now I am using Beanstalkd and Laravel forge for my queues which I fire like this: `dispatch(new ProcessPodcast($podcast));`

But how do I push a queue into a different job that has a low priority? This will only push the queue into a different job but not set the priority: `$job = (new ProcessPodcast($podcast))->onQueue('processing'); dispatch($job);`

And if a queue job has a low priority does it mean that it will be fired later when there arent that many queues or how does low priority jobs work?

Comment: The [queue priorities](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#queue-priorities) section doesn't answer your question?

Comment: @WojciechMleczek No, does it mean that I must use different queue drivers depening on priority? I only want to use beanstalk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dispatch((new Job)->onQueue('high'));
```

This piece of code create new `Job` class instance, serialize it and store in queue named *high*, but it not means that this queue is a special one. Moreover this queue could have less priority than the *low* queue! This is just a string you use to name queue, of course it's highly recommended to follow some patterns to make code more readable for other developers.

In [`config/queue.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/queue.php#L47) file you can define the default queue name which will be processed. If you create queue worker using `php artisan queue:work` command then it'll listen job request on that queue. However, you may overwrite default value using `--queue` parameter in `queue:work` command:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=high,low # or --queue=high,medium,low
```

This command also set the priority of the queues. As long as there's any job request in the *high* queue it will be processed before any request in the *low* queue.